# HibernateCursorItemReader Result set already closed

Tags: java, hibernate, session, spring-batch

I'm using a spring batch HibernateCursorItemReader, it's defined as follows

```
    <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.HibernateCursorItemReader"
      scope="step" id="priceListFctrItemReader">
    <property name="queryName" value="FIND_ALL_PRICE_LIST_FCTR_ITEM_ID_BY_MONTRY_FCTR_VER"/>
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
    <property name="parameterValues">
        <map>
            <entry key="factorVersion" value="#{jobParameters['current.factor.version']}"/>
            <entry key="trueValue" value="#{true}"/>
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>
```

On small results it seems to be fine. But if processing takes long it seems the session closes and I get

```
org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not advance using next()
at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:54)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:126)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:112)
```

and further down

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Result set already closed
at weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.ResultSet.checkResultSet(ResultSet.java:144)
at weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.ResultSet.preInvocationHandler(ResultSet.java:93)
```

I don't experience this in spring-boot, but on weblogic I do. It could be that local spring boot is just faster.

any ideas on how to avoid this ?

Comment: I've since tried a JdbcCursorItemReader with the same results. As soon as it tries to move the cursor, the result set is closed and it fails. Even with a commit-interval of 1. I suspect the resultset is closed when the step writes. I've tried setting useSharedExtendedConnection to true with a datasource that supports that. no luck. I'm running on weblogic, I think weblogic might be the problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that spring-batch does a commit after every chunk, and committing closes the transaction and thus the result set.

When you are not in an application container, like when you are using spring boot, *CursorItemReaders use a separate connection to bypass the transaction and thereby avoid the commit which closes the cursor result set.

On the other hand, if you are running on an application server the connection you get from the server managed *data source* will by default take part in a transaction. In order for a cursor item reader to work you must set up a *data source* which does not take part in transactions.<sup>[a](https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2012/03/transactions-in-spring-batch-part-2-restart-cursor-based-reading-and-listeners/)</sup>

Alternatively, you may be able to use a *PagingItemReader which reads *page size* records per chunk, each in a separate transaction. This completely avoids the problem of a closing result set. **Beware:** If the underlying table changes between chunks the results may not be what you expect!

---

[a] : https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2012/03/transactions-in-spring-batch-part-2-restart-cursor-based-reading-and-listeners/